# Creating a web site webdeploy package when solution builds

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, msbuild-wpp

I have a VS 2010 WCF service solution which I would like to deploy to IIS 7.5 servers via web deploy package. I would like to have the web deploy package generated when the WCF service project builds. I have seen other examples of how to initiate a web deploy packaging after build via importing MS Build targets for web deploy into the .csproj. But I cannot wrap my head around things which I am may or may not be able to to do this way.

I want my web deploy package to do the following tasks when deployed on a target server:

- Create a new web site on the target server with an app pool to target framework 4.0 which uses NETWORK SERVICE identity
- Add site bindings to enable net.tcp on a specific port and enable http and net.tcp prootocols
- Create a web application under this new site to point to a specific file system folder
- Run a .bat file to start couple of net.tcp related services to support non http WCF activation

From whatever I have read about web deploy, some of these can be done via webdeploy manifest files and including specific providers. What I am not understanding is telling the MS build packaging mechanism to pass the providers to include in the manifest and the values. I am fairly new to Web deploy and any help/pointers to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first three items can be done using the [`appHostConfig`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569080%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) provider, which should be included if you set the `IncludeIisSettings` and `UseIis` properties both to `true`.

The last item can be done via the [`runCommand`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) provider either as part of your manifest or via [`preSync` / `postSync`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

WPP (the MSBuild stuff on top of MSDeploy) has no support for `preSync` / `postSync`, but you can include the `runCommand` provider explicitly using `MsDeploySourceManifest`:

```
<!-- Create a WebProjectName.wpp.targets file in the root 
     of your web application (WebProjectName)
-->
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AfterAddContentPathToSourceManifest>
      $(AfterAddContentPathToSourceManifest);
      AddPostSyncProviders
    </AfterAddContentPathToSourceManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AddPostSyncProviders">
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
      <Path>absolute path to exe on target machine</Path>
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

FYI - `runCommand` can only execute absolute paths on the target machine [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867758/msdeploy-runcommand-using-relative-path).

Comment: Appreciate your time on this and I like this idea. However, I would like to disagree on using _appHostConfig_ for creating the Website. I tried that already and MS Deploy always fails if the site does not already exists.

Comment: The way how I worked around it was by keeping a separate .cmd file included in the project and copying them over to the package folder via xcopy on post build event. I have couple of appCmd commands in the above said .cmd file to set the application pool and site on the target server. I then launch the MS Deploy generated .cmd file from this batch file to kick start the MS Deploy process. I know this is ugly but it just works :(.

Comment: I receive an error: The element <Path> beneath element <MsDeploySourceManifest> is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I take is to use MSBuild to build the package and MSDeploy to deploy it to the server.  I use the following command line, in my case I'm using cruise control:

```
/p:Configuration=Release 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=Package 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=$(SolutionName)/$(ProjectName) 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<servername>:8172/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:username=<username>
/p:password=<password>
/p:EnablePackageProcessLoggingAndAssert=True
/p:PackageLocation=$(WorkingMainDir)$(ProjectName)$(ProjectType)\Package\$(SolutionName).zip
/p:IntermediateOutputPath=$(WorkingMainDir)$(ProjectName)$(ProjectType)\Temp\
/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=true
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true
```

I then use msdeploy to deploy the resulting package, the following link (the accepted answer) is a good write up on how to do this:

[msdeploy (Web Deploy) failing with 401 auth issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428562/msdeploy-web-deploy-failing-with-401-auth-issues)

Answer (score -2):

Tried that but project fails to load thereafter: The element < Path > beneath < MsDeploySourceManifest > is unrecognized.

Comment: This answer does not help.